# Python opening untitled window instead of IDLE

Tags: python

When I open Python, it opens the untitled file window instead of `SHELL`. I tried reinstalling, changing, repairing and modifying. HELP PLEASE.
Python version: 3.7 32-bit

Edit:

It opens
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IGHC2uvjyEs-5GAdCNDs1a5ra3IQQJLr/view?usp=drivesdk

instead of this `SHELL`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I8VZcn6prJQuTzozTCRXsLgrJvBipSsg/view?usp=drivesdk when I start `IDLE`.

Comment: You need to open the link called `Idle`, not `Python`.  The `Python` link opens a generic command window.

Comment: Search for `IDLE`, not `Python`. If you search for `Python`, it will open only the console-based app, which is something like the interactive mode in `IDLE`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say, so I assume you're running Python on Windows.  If so you will get multiple links installed in your startup menu.  Use the one named `IDLE`, not the one named `Python`.

[image]

At least this is what you get if you download the installer directly from https://www.python.org/, it may differ if you're using the Windows Store for example.

Comment: @ANGSHUMAN you're going to have to do a much better job of describing your problem, and I'd recommend editing the question to do it.  If you have a file menu, it sounds like you're already running IDLE.

Comment: Sorry,I meant to say that when I start IDLE it opens untitled window instead of SHELL.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate option to this is installing Anaconda on your system . It gives you option of using Spyder which is IDLE and also jupyter notebook .